# Can you use the C open(const char* name, int flag) function on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, unix, gnu

I am trying to port a library to run on the iPhone which makes use of memory mapping and a bunch of other stuff. I noticed a bunch of #defines missing as well (O_RDONLY) which should be defined in `<fcntl.h>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use it, but the `fcntl.h` header is not included in the Foundation or UIKit frameworks by default. To use the `open(2)` system call, simply import that header wherever you use it (or add it to your pre-compiled header file).

For example:

```
#import <fcntl.h>

// now you can use open or import your library header files
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not? The only problem that it might have is apple not accepting it, as they scan programs for system calls. But I believe an open system call is fine.

Answer (score 0):

worked code for me:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>

- (BOOL) openFile:(NSString *)filePath ......{
...
const char * filePathStr = [filePath UTF8String];
int fd = open(filePathStr, O_RDONLY);
...
}
```